# How to hide a td element using using classname

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

```
    <table>
      <tbody>
        <tr>
         <td class="A">More Html element</td>
         <td class="B">More html element</td>
        </tr>
       <tr>
         <td class="A">More Html element</td>
         <td class="B">More html element</td>.....(2)
      </tr>
      <tbody>
   <table>
```

How using jquery I can hide the element at number 2?

Answer (score 4):

You can allso use [nth-child selector](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/) , like this `$('td.B:nth-child(2)').hide();`, but i don't realy recomend hiding td elements as you're table might go "wild" in some cases , you should hide the content of the td element ( `<td class="B"><span class="hideMe">sadsa</span></td>` , so you're jquery selector for hiding would look like `$('td.B:nth-child(2) .hideMe').hide();`

Answer (score 2):

`$("TABLE TD.b").eq(1).hide();`

Note though, that this may cause layout issues with cells moving accross your table. A better solution would be to have a container div inside the cell and hide that instead.

Answer (score 1):

Example -

```
$('td.B').eq(1).hide();
```

Use the [eq](http://api.jquery.com/eq/) to select the specified index.

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/nWwWb/1/)